# android Google maps API map will not load, Authentication error

Tags: android, google-maps, groovy

SO I'm developing an app for android using the groovy plugin.
and I'm facing an issue with google maps where **the map loads fine if i set the map activity in the application manifest as the main activity**,

but **if i set the main activity to be my login screen instead and just go through the application flow, whenever i get to the same map activity, it will not load at all**.
and i get the below error in Logcat.
*E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).*

Comment: Have you generated google map API key using your SHA with application Id?

Comment: yes, as i said if i just set the main activity in the manifest to the maps activity ( make the application open directly to the map from launcher) everything works fine

Comment: "he map loads fine if i set the map activity in the application manifest as the main activity" - do you mean launcher activity ?

Comment: yes exactly, if it is set as launcher activity it runs fine, if not it will not load

Answer (score 0):

Give the proper SHA key in the Google console and run time permission for loading the map.